# Как можно указать количество итераций в SciKit-Learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, линейная-алгебра

Как можно указать количество итераций в SciKit-Learn?

Comment: в SciKit-Learn многие сотни классов, функций и методов - о каком конкретно вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Linear Regression

Answer (score 2):

Во многих классах и методах SciKit-Learn можно указать максимальное число итераций (параметр `max_iter`), после которого метод / функция будет остановлена, даже если ещё не сошлась. В этом случае будет выведено предупреждение что функция не сошлась и что следует увеличить значение параметра `max_iter`.

---

**UPDATE:** для `LinearRegression` нет смысла указывать число итераций, т.к. в данном методе используется [метод наименьших квадратов](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) для которого, в свою очередь, коэффициенты могут быть найдены при помощи операций над матрицами.